# Excel COUNTIFS where the condition is row-specific

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to do a COUNTIF on the following data where the criteria is row specific and does not link to a specific value or cell.

For example, in the following example, I am trying to count the rows where column B is double of column A.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 |

I assume the correct syntax is "=COUNTIF(B:B, "="&A:A *2) so that it checks if column B in each row is twice of column A, but I always get 0. The correct result would be 2.

Seems like only discrete #s or a single cell reference ("="&A2 for example) are allowed, however I'd like the condition to check against to be specific to each row.

Is there a different function or some syntax errors that prevent me from doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4*2=B1:B4))
```

[image]

note: in your sample data, the result *should* be zero, I have added one line to achieve a non zero result

Answer (score 0):

Your example data has no (rows) instances where B column is twice that of the value in A

`=SUM(IF(B1:B3 =A1:A3*2,1,0))` as a 3D/array formula will do it for you.

An array formula has to be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> in LibreOffice; i'm not entirely shure if it is the same in Excel *(and have no means to try)*.

Comment: Editing while cybernetic.nomad answered.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with the original formula is that it needs summed somehow. One way is how `cybernetic.nomad` did it. Another is to simply enclose the poster's formula in a `SUM()` function.

There are other ways of achieving a list of 1's and 0's for whether column B values meet the condition. `Hannu` shows one that frankly would have been my "goto" because I never found a lot of use for the `COUNT` family of functions. (My limitation, I know, as the last eight years or so of looking at Excel help sites has shown me many "off-label" uses as well as them being more direct ways to get results I always used `IF()` for.)

However, there're other ways of doing that too, one of which is a simple TRUE/FALSE test for each value that does not use `IF()` in its working, so probably would be faster over a large data set:

```
=SUM(  (B1:B4 = A1:A4*2)  *1)
```

It's just the simple comparison, generating an array of TRUE/FALSE results. Then one can use the `--` operators, as `cybernetic.nomad` does, or the `*1` as I do here. This converts the literal TRUE/FALSE array elements into 1/0 array elements allowing `SUM()` to then add them. (My preference is the `*1` as it is easy to not add at the end of the expression if the expression has its own multiplication in it as that multiplication (or addition if doing an `OR` instead of an `AND`) is sufficient for the conversion. Of course, either works nicely, and for many the `--` seems clearer and so would make it easier for THEM to maintain than the `*1` would. We humans are like that and to each, the best for him.)

The `COUNT` family produces the 1/0's directly though so that's a nice value there. However, something still has to sum things up when applying it like this over a range.